# how to resolve a return labeled as [object promise]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I understand this is a rather noobish question but i have been stuck here for about thirty minutes now.

UPDATE: temp fix but not what i am looking for. Still open for answers.

main route test below. (works fine, but is way more sloppy than i'd like.)

```
api.get('/', async(req, res) => {

    let prefix = prefixSchema.find({})
    let prefixData = []
    prefix.select('prefix')
    prefix.exec(function(err, data) {
        data.map(function(obj) {
            prefixData.push(obj.prefix)
        })
        res.render('index.pug', { prefix: prefixData[0] })
    })

})
```

I can not get this section below (snippet from controller) to pass the object through to the route. Once more extremely noobish question but i am cramming a fair amount of info into a quick self learning session.

```
    async getPrefix() {
        let prefix = this._db.find({})
        let prefixData = []
        prefix.select('prefix')
        prefix.exec(function(err, data) {
            data.map(function(obj) {
                prefixData.push(obj.prefix)
            })
            console.log(prefixData[0]) // logs the proper value
            return prefixData[0] // returns [Object Promise] when called through the API


        })
    }
```

Comment: That's what `async` does

Answer (score 1):

```
//define a function to handle the data returned when promise is resolved
function toDoWithPromiseReturnedData(data){
    // Work on data
}

function onError(err){
    // If any error is occurred in function toDoWithPromiseReturnedData
}

var returnedPromise=getPrefix();
//add other required lines of code
returnedPromise.then(toDoWithPromiseReturnedData)
.catch(onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a misunderstanding of your promise. A promise is just an expectation that you want to do something with your data after it is returned. all it says is if you com back with data then i want you to do x, if you come back with an error I want you to do y. Here you haven't set any instructions for what the code should do with the data. Try adding this after your function:

```
getPrefix().then(function(result) {
    // you can access the result from the promise here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code for the getPrefix function, the main return statement should be outside of the prefix.exec() function, this could be achieved like:

```
    async getPrefix() {
        let prefix = this.find({})
        let prefixData = []
        prefix.select('prefix')
        const dataToReturn = prefix.exec(function(err, data) {
            data.map(function(obj) {
                prefixData.push(obj.prefix)
            })
            console.log(prefixData[0]) // logs the proper value
            return prefixData[0] // returns the proper value to dataToReturn variable
        })
        return dataToReturn;
    }
```

then in the API (router) function while calling, the getPrefix function, you can call it like:

```
api.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    let prefix = await prefixSchema.getPrefix()
    res.render('index.pug', { prefix })
})
```

Comment: This is super similar to how i had approached this the first time. Logging it once the route was called always returned an undefined value. Even after sending it through a function to resolve it.

Comment: @LegoGatTrooper have you tried running this piece of code, I have edited it slightly to remove the `_db` after `this` in the getPrefix function.